# HOW to convert string In JSON that has html objects with stringify function?

Tags: javascript, html, json

In Object that contains HTML element objects key of 'elem'

```
var obj = {
   param1:"",
   elem:document.createElement('script').textContent = 'alert("JSON stringify")';
}
```

I try to convert the obj into string using

```
JSON.stringify(obj);
```

It gets only elem as empty Object.

```
{
"param":"",
"elem":{}
}
```

My question is :

1. Why it returns empty object when call stringify function in JSON?
2. Is it possible to convert the HTML elements also as string?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```js
var elemString = document.createElement('script').textContent = 'alert("JSON stringify")';

var obj = {
   param1:"",
   elem: elemString 
}

var objectString = JSON.stringify(obj);

console.log(objectString);


var elemString2 =  " document.createElement('script').textContent = 'alert(\"JSON stringify\")'";

var obj2 = {
   param1:"",
   elem: elemString2 
}

var objectString2 = JSON.stringify(obj2);

console.log(objectString2);
```

**1. Why it returns empty object when call stringify function in JSON?**

Ans: Because the way you are adding the elem it is not getting converted to a String value, so it is not getting stored. Moreover it will actually throw an error.

**2. Is it possible to convert the HTML elements also as string?**

Ans: Yes. Look at the code examples I provided.

Answer (score 2):

An `HTMLElement` is treated as a plain object by `JSON.stringify()` because it doesn't implement a `toJSON()` method. That's  why the result looks like an empty object.

If you want to convert the `HTMLElement` to a string you'll have to implement that function yourself. Luckily, you can use the `outerHTML` property:

```
var scriptElem = document.createElement('script');
scriptElem.textContent = 'alert("JSON stringify")';
var obj = {
  param1: "",
  elem: scriptElem.outerHTML
}
```

It's also possible to implement the `toJSON()` method on `HTMLElement.prototype` and then your original code would work as is:

```
HTMLElement.prototype.toJSON = function() { return this.outerHTML; };
```

However, extending the prototype of host objects is generally considered bad practice and `toJSON()` specifically breaks earlier versions of the Prototype.js library (as if that matters anymore).

Answer (score 0):

`JSON.stringify` cannot convert functions in object(HTML objects has in built functions) and retrieve it back , you can use `jsonfn` plugin http://www.eslinstructor.net/jsonfn/ instead

Answer (score 0):

1. `JSON.stringify` Can't convert HTML DOM or functions to json. See [this](https://gist.github.com/sstur/7379870) link.
2. Use `innerHTML` to get html as string.

Answer (score -5):

```
JSON.parse(content);
```

Try **replace stringify by parse** ? 
*(i'm not sure)*

Comment: That makes absolutely no sense at all. `JSON.parse` takes a string of JSON and converts it into a JavaScript data a structure. `obj` is not a string.